# Correct syntax for multiple category ID's in array

Tags: category, array

Trying to exclude the rendering of something based on category ID using the following...

```
<?php if ($_category_id == 2) { ?>
    <?php //do nothing ?>
<?php } else { ?>
    <?php //do something ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I need to specify multiple category ID's for exclusion however so I gather these need to be loaded into an array.

```
<?php $ignoredcats = array(2,360,124); ?>
<?php if (count(array_intersect($ignoredcats,$_category_id))) { ?>
    <?php //do nothing ?>
<?php } else { ?>
    <?php //do something ?>
<?php } ?>
```

This doesn't work though. How should I be specifying by multiple category ID please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think u may looking for,

```
 $ignoredcats = array(2,360,124);
 if (in_array($_category_id, $ignoredcats )){
   //do nothing
 }
 else{
   //do something
 }
```

Comment: Could have sworn I tried this actually - either way - correct answer and this works - thanks. Accepted this answer as just pipped @Marius's.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `in_array()`.

```
<?php $ignoredcats = array(2,360,124); ?>
<?php if (in_array($_category_id, $ignoredcats)) { ?>
    <?php //category is in $ignoredcats  ?>
<?php } else { ?>
    <?php //category is not in $ignoredcats ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Could have sworn I tried this actually - either way - correct answer and this works - thanks. Accepted @Helphin's answer as just pipped yours first.